# google maps api v3 with 'Qf[F] is undefined' error and subsequent grey / uncentered

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been messing around with this all night and cannot fix the problem.  I am loading google maps api v3 into a boostrap 3 ajax modal.  On click of .dtMap, I load my modal page into the modal div... open/show it... then load the map options with google loader.

On first click everything shows properly, but I receive a 'TypeError: Qf[F] is undefined' error in the console.

Upon closing the modal and opening it again the above error is gone, BUT, the map only shows in the top left of its 'window'.  The rest of the map is light grey.  I have found some 'solutions' to this grey problem such as [solution link](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/google-maps-in-hidden-div), but cannot seem to get it working with my implementation.

I can confirm for the second part that if I resize my browser the map is corrected, but no longer centered.

So, any help with these two would be greatly appreciated.

**JS stuff :**

```
// show google map
$('#datatable').on('click', '.dtMap', function () {

    $('#modal-ajax').load('/modals/m_view_map.php', function() {
        $(this).modal('show');
        google.load('maps','3', {other_params:'sensor=false', callback: function(){

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.4889, -98.3987)
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.4889, -98.3987),
                map: map
            });

        }});

    });

});
```

**EDIT w/ partial solution :**

When my modal opens I have it set to fade at 400. I am now delaying the loading of the map by 400 so it is in position (no long fading) when it is loaded.  This has solved the centering and grey areas.

I am STILL receiving a 'TypeError: Qf[F] is undefined' error upon the first modal open/map open.  If I close the modal and open again any number of times after this initial time the error no longer appears.  Can anyone shed more light on what this error is?  It does not appear to affect anything in terms of operation/looks though.

```
// show google map
$('#datatable').on('click', '.dtMap', function () {

    var data = {
      'activity_id': $(this).parents('tr').attr('id')
    };

    $('#modal-ajax').load('/modals/m_view_map.php', data,
        function() {
            $(this).modal('show');
            // wait till modal opens (400)
            setTimeout(function (){

                google.load('maps','3', {other_params:'sensor=false', callback: function(){

                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.4889, -98.3987);

                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 12,
                        center: latLng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'test'
                    });

                }});    

            }, 400);
      });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map looks moved inside the div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388816/google-map-looks-moved-inside-the-div)

Comment: Looked and tried the solution and what was different - still doesn't work.

Comment: Does your modal have a size?  Are you triggering the resize event once it is shown?

Comment: I have been trying to trigger the resize and center it as per all of the solutions I have found yet can't seem to get it working.  The shows fine on the first click (minus the Qf error) then all after that are un-centered with grey areas.  If I resize my browser the grey disappears, however, it is still un-centered. Also the Qf error disappears after the initial opening of the modal/map.

Comment: #map_canvas is set to height:250px; width:100%.  The site is responsive as is the modal.

Comment: -1?  The 'may already have an answer' answer does not work for this case.

Comment: percentage widths are problematic.  Does it _really_ have a non-zero size reported to the API when the map is initialized?